# incomprehensible error on this simple create table query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, export

I've just exported the CREATE sql of a singular table using phpmyadmin. this is the result:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `register_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `account_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

But when i run this code on the very phpmyadmin i receive this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREME' at line 14
```

I have tried many ways, but my skills aren't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add comma before `PRIMARY KEY (id)`

```
`name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   -- <== this
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

add comma and it will work, [see this fiddle (click link)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b142)